# Diagonal matrix of consecutive numbers

Tags: python-2.7, matrix, canopy

I want to create a diagonal matrix below's the code in python 2.7

```
def diag(steps):
    '''
    steps : a positive integer
    '''
    matrix = [[0]*steps]*steps    # matrix of the order step x step
    for i in range(steps + 1):
        matrix[i][i] = i + 1    # i'th' element of 'i'th row
    return matrix
```

For eg: if step = 3, I should get [ [1, 0, 0], [0, 2, 0], [0, 0, 3] ].
But I'm getting [ [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3] ]
Can anyone help me with this bug and please tell what's wrong with my logic?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python list of lists, changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: you should validate an anwser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By multiplying an array you don't create a matrix with three different arrays. You create multiple references to the same array.

Example:

```
> a = [2,2,2]
> b = [a]*3
> print b
[[2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2], [2, 2, 2]]
> a[1] = 4
> print b
[[2, 4, 2], [2, 4, 2], [2, 4, 2]]
> b[0][0] = 8
> print b 
[[8, 4, 2], [8, 4, 2], [8, 4, 2]]
```

You see? Every first element in every 3-array is now 8, not only b[0][0]. That is because they all are the same object.

You have to change

```
matrix = [[0]*steps]*steps
```

to

```
# probably not the best pythonic way but it works
matrix = [[0 for x in range(steps)] for x in range(steps)]
```

Answer (score 0):

1) For convenience, you may consider using `numpy` which allows to work in a more 'mathematical' way instead of python's list.
In your case you may want to look at `numpy.diag(vector)` which create a `len(vector)xlen(vector)` matrix where `matrix[i][i] = vector[i]`

For your need, using numpy you can do:

```
import numpy as np
matrix = np.diag( list(range(1, steps+1))
```

And thats all

2) To anwser your precise question (in case you can't use numpy for some reason) you could make it short:

```
def diag(steps):
    matrix = [ [0]*i+[i+1]+[0]*(steps-i-1) for i in range(steps) ]
    return matrix
```

Comment: Sure I will eventually after I've earned 15 reputations. I can't upvote till then. Sorry

Comment: Validating the question is even more important for next users getting here :)